# Cakephp saving 10 new rows after checking id of the user

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to create 10 new rows in controller if the userid is not found in the user_id row. I tried create() function and then save() function but it doesn't seem to do the job.
Below is the code, is there a way we can solve this issue?

```
function invite_fellows(){

        //Read userid
        $userid = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');

        $invite_table = $this->User->Invite->findbyUserId($userid);

        if(empty($invite_table)){
            $code_limit = 10;
            //Save 10 unique codes for the user
            for($i=0; $i<$code_limit;$i++){
                $unique_id = $this->_unique($userid); // Unique id with userid as initial prefix
                $this->data['Invite'] = array('user_id' => $userid, 'code' => $unique_id);
                $this->User->Invite->create();
                $this->User->Invite->save($this->data['Invite']);
            }
        }


        //Find user in users and associated tables
        $user = $this->User->findbyId($userid);

        //Find user in invite table
        $confirmed = $this->User->Invite->find('count', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $userid,'invited_user >' => 0)));
        $this->set(compact('user','confirmed'));
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to do the job" mean? Do you get errors? Does it save only one row instead, or no rows at all?

Comment: Sorry it doesn't save any rows at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely there's a validation rule that blocks the save. Try adding `debug( $this->User->Invite->validationErrors );` after the `save()` to check for that. Make sure debug level is set to at least 1 in core.php.

Comment: OK I found the error. I've a few fields that are validated but didn't exist in the table columns. I still need to validate those as they are used for my userform. Do you think I should use this in controller function instead for my userform separately? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can disable validation when saving: `$this->User->Invite->save( $this->data['Invite'], false );`